# Estimate power for linear model with Bernoulli-distributed error

Tags: maximum-likelihood, linear-model, heteroscedasticity, statistical-power

I want to estimate a linear model for a phenotype $y_i$ defined by a liability threshold model, using observable data $x_i, c_i$.

$$y_i = \mu + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$$

$$\text{Pr}(\epsilon_i | x_i, \beta, \mu) \sim B(1, p_i) - p_i$$

$p_i$ is a complicated function of the normal CDF of the underlying error for the liability threshold model, which is itself based on a linear model with a different set of parameters, but for the purpose of this problem, I think the only important fact is that we cannot assume that $\epsilon_i$ is drawn from the same distribution for every individual $i$.

I want to do maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters, and in particular, find the power of the estimates, but I'm not sure what to do because the errors are not only heteroskedastic, but depend on the individual.

Comment: You're treating the $p_i$ as known, or estimated with uncertainty?

Comment: For simplicity in this case, $p_i$ is known.